# I have an 2d array of Qt objects that I've seeded with values. how do I access the values of a particular object in the array and change them?

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

My tiles.cpp file is where i'm trying to access the object at rect[someint][someint] so that I can use my ai to change the pieces on the board. Right now it's done through clicking on a particular tile and passing that tiles info along to validate if the move is correct. What I'm having trouble doing is figuring out how to change a tile without being able to access it through a click.

When i try to change a value of rect like rect[someint][someint]->piece=0 i get a invalid types unresolved overloaded function type [int] for array subscipt rect[tempy][tempx] error.

Some of my main file above main function:

```
Tile * rect[8][8];

void chessBoard(QWidget *baseWidget, Tile *rect[8][8]){

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    boardX = 350;
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
        //seed tile array with tile objects
        rect[i][j] = new Tile(baseWidget);
        rect[i][j]->tileColor=(i+j)%2;
        rect[i][j]->piece=0;
        rect[i][j]->row=i;
        rect[i][j]->col=j;
        rect[i][j]->tileNum=k++;
        rect[i][j]->tileDisplay();
        rect[i][j]->setGeometry(boardX,boardY,64,64);

        //rect[i][j]->setScaledContents(true);

        boardX += 64;
    }
    boardY += 64;
}
```

a small part of Tile.cpp:

```
Pieces *isValid = new Pieces();
extern Tile * rect[8][8];
extern QWidget *myWidget;

Tile *click1;

void Tile::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event){
    moveChecking(this, ++count);
}

Tile::moveChecking(Tile *temp, int countC){


if(countC==1){
    if(temp->piece && (temp->pieceColor==turns%2)){


        if(temp->pieceName != " "){
            tempx = temp->col;
            tempy = temp->row;
            click1 = new Tile();

            temp->setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: green;}");

            click1=temp;
        } else {
            count = 0;
        }
    } else {
        count = 0;
    }

} else {

    if(temp->tileNum==click1->tileNum){
        click1->tileDisplay();
        count = 0;

    } else {
        //ready coordinates to give to Pieces
        tempx = click1->col;
        tempy = click1->row;
        tempx2 = temp->col;
        tempy2 = temp->row;
        //give coordinates of piece origin and possible landing
        isValid->coordinates(tempx, tempy, tempx2, tempy2);

        //check if input coordinates are a valid move for piece and player
        if(isValid->whichPiece() == true){

            //switch Qwidget values on origin and spot piece landed
            click1->piece=0;
            temp->piece=1;

            //give moved piece same attributes
            temp->pieceColor=click1->pieceColor;
            temp->pieceName=click1->pieceName;


            click1->display(click1->pieceName);
            temp->display(click1->pieceName);

            click1->tileDisplay();
            temp->tileDisplay();



            turns++;
            count = 0;

            if(aiOn == 1){
                aiTurn(temp);
            }


        } else {

            count = 1;
        }

    }

  }

}
```

On the ai turn is where i'm totally stuck trying to figure out how to access a given tile at coordinates y, x in the array of tile objects. Thanks for any help at all!

Ai function. Doesn't do what I need it to at the moment which is change the pieces on the Gui board. The error i've mentioned shows up at the @@@ signs.

```
void Tile::aiTurn(Tile *temp){
    int aiIsThinking = 1;

    Ai_Logic *newMove = new Ai_Logic;

    while(aiIsThinking == 1){
        newMove->calculateBestMove();


        //ready coordinates to give to Pieces
        tempx = aiX;
        tempy = aiY;
        tempx2 = aiX1;
        tempy2 = aiY1;
        //give coordinates of piece origin and possible landing
        isValid->coordinates(tempx, tempy, tempx2, tempy2);

        //check if input coordinates are a valid move for piece and player
        if(isValid->whichPiece() == true){


            aiClick = new Tile();
            //aiClick = &rect[tempy][tempx];
            aiClick1 = new Tile();

            rect[tempx][tempy]->pieceName = "P"; //@@@

            //simulating ai clicking start piece
            aiClick->row = tempx;
            aiClick->col = tempy;
            //aiClick->pieceColor = rect[tempx][tempy].pieceColor;

            //simulating ai clicking landing spot
            aiClick1->row = tempx2;
            aiClick1->col = tempy2;

            //tile color corrections
            aiClick -> tileColor=(tempx+tempy)%2;
            aiClick1 -> tileColor=(tempx2+tempx2)%2;


            //switch Qwidget values on origin and spot piece landed
            aiClick->piece=0;
            aiClick->pieceName = " ";
            aiClick1->piece=1;

            //give moved piece same color at landing
            for(int k = 0; k < 8; k++){
                if(boardArr[tempy2][tempx2] == whitePieces[k]){
                    aiClick1->pieceColor=0;

                } else if (boardArr[tempy2][tempx2] == blackPieces[k]){
                    aiClick1->pieceColor=1;
                }
            }


           // aiClick1->pieceColor=aiClick->pieceColor;
            aiClick1->pieceName=boardArr[tempy2][tempx2];

            //display piece having moved
            aiClick->display(aiClick->pieceName);
            aiClick1->display(aiClick->pieceName);

            //make sure tile color is correct
            aiClick->tileDisplay();
            aiClick1->tileDisplay();

            turns++;
            count = 0;
            aiIsThinking = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are not showing the relevant code. Where do you get the error? What is the exact error message?

Comment: I might have edited it after you read my question when I try to change rect  by doing rect[someInt][someInt]->piece = 0; It gives me an error : invalid types unresolved overloaded function type [int] error.

Comment: Is piece an int? Or is it a string of some kind?

Comment: Yeah it is an int. I get that same error even if I'm trying to change rect[y][x]->pieceName which is a string.

Comment: Side note: Why do you go click1 = new Tile(); then assign temp to click1? Won't that leak the new Tile ? Are you getting the error in the moveChecking function?

Comment: whole error is actually: invalid types unresolved overloaded function type [int] for array subscipt rect[tempy][tempx] error. With an up arrow under tempx

Comment: Not in the move check function, that works fine. I probably showed the wrong bits of code. My issue is i'm trying to figure out how to access the object stored at rect[y][x] without clicking on it as i do in the moveChecking function. When i write rect[y][x]->(any variable in Tiles object) i get the invalid types unresolved overloaded function type [int] for array subscipt rect[tempy][tempx] error. With an up arrow under tempx

Comment: What does your function on the ai turn look like? What are the params? If this is it aiTurn(temp), you are passing a Tile.

Comment: My ai function has nothing passed to it at the moment. It grabs extern variables of x, y, x1, y1. I'm semi new to coding/c++ and I don't know how i'd pass it the particular tile of rect I need. Whoops i see that temp is being passed to it, it's unused at the moment because i figured it was the wrong tile (since i'm calling the ai function right after the users turn)

Comment: Can you post the ai function?

Comment: Just posted it at the bottom of my post. Currently it doesn't do what I need it to do and i've been experimenting with different options.

Comment: Basically all the aiClick/1->some variable are completely useless to me right now and need to be replaced with aiClick = rect[y][x] or some other form of altering rect[y][x] then displaying it

Comment: So this doesn't compile at the moment right? Is rect[][] a member of your class? Has rect[tempx][tempy] been initialized?

Comment: Yeah, the only error is at the @@@ signs, but the rest of the function also doesn't do what i need it to at the moment. I need aiClick/1 to = rect[y][x]. rect[][] is the extern array which holds all 64 tile objects extern Tile *rect[8][8]. for the moveChecking the particular tile object inside the rect array is passed by a mouseEvent when it's clicked on.

Comment: Hmm, something like this _should_ work :
// Delcare tile pointers
Tile *aiClick;
Tile *aiClick1;

// assign the pointer to a specific tile on the board
aiClick = rect[tempx][tempy];
aiClick1 = new Tile();  // Create a new Tile for Click1

aiClick->pieceName = "P"; //@@@
...
Formatting is not so good :(

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far, I did a really bad job explaining what my problem was so sorry about that! When I write Tile *aiClick; aiClick = rect[tempy][tempx]; I get the same error unresolved overload function type [int] for array subscipt :(. I don't know how else to access the particular tile I need!

Comment: As rect[][] is full of pointers to Tiles you should be able to assign a Tile pointer with an array location so I think there is a problem with rect somewhere else.

Comment: I think I was able to solve it by writing ::rect[y][x]. Would that make sense? The rect[8][8] is declared as an extern in my tiles.cpp file then as a Tiles * rect[8][8] in my main.cpp file.

Comment: Ahh ok. So that means it is a scoping issue. Generally you would define  member variables in your .h files. So you might define Tiles *rect[8][8]; in your tiles.h file and then #include "tiles.h" in your main.h or main.cpp (depending on your needs). Without seeing all the code I don't completely understand the structure of your code. I am happy that you got it working. :)

Comment: Yeah me too, was super stumped! Thanks for all the help, very much appreciate it.

Comment: @MaxC Please consider creating an answer yourself for later reference.

Answer (score 0):

I did a poor job of explaining what my problem was in my post. Simply, I'd created an extern array of qt widget objects called rect[8][8]. This was defined in my tiles.cpp file as an extern, and again in my main.cpp as a Tiles * rect[8][8]. I wasn't able to access it through rect[y][x]->some property. However using ::rect[y][x]-> some property worked perfectly.